# access let variables in describe block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

so i'm trying to write a spec for this method:

```
class Student
has_many :payments
  def payments_by_year
    payments.group_by { |payment| payment.payment_date.year }
  end
end
```

i made my spec look like this:

```
RSpec.describe Student do
  let!(:student) { create :student, first_name: 'Bruce', last_name: 'Wayne' }
  let!(:student2) { create :student, first_name: 'Peter', last_name: 'Parker' }
  let!(:payment) { create :payment, student: student, payment_date: Date.new(2016,9,1) }
  let!(:payment2) { create :payment, student: student, payment_date: Date.new(2016,8,1) }
  let!(:payment3) { create :payment, student: student, payment_date: Date.new(2015,7,1) }

  describe '#payments_by_year' do
    describe 'returns hash of payments with years as keys' do
      subject { student.payments_by_year }

      it { is_expected.to eq ####SOMETHING SHOULD BE HERE}
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is i dont know what pass to the `:eq` method, since i cannot access let variables without exception:

```
`payment` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). (RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError)
```

So i cannot hardcode correct results. How can i access these variables in the `describe` block?

Comment: You shouldn't access them from `describe` block, but from `it` block _within_ the `describe` block (read the error you get).